# ¿Cómo limpiar los datos de dropdown list anidados con jquery en ASP.Net C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hola amigos espero me puedan ayudar con este problema de antemano muchas gracias.

Mi problema es que tengo cuatro `dropdownList` en cascada por lo que al consultar con mi botón `html` requiero limpiarlos. En `webForms` con `c#` se que es de esta forma `ddlAños.SelectedIndex = 0;` lo cual me lo hace perfecto pero con `jquery` no lo he logrado espero me puedan ayudar.

Aquí coloco mi código:

```js
//Esta es una forma 
$("[id*=ddlAños]").prop('selectedIndex' ,0);

//Esta es otra forma 
$("[id*=ddlAños]").val(0);

/7Ninguna forma me ha funcionado ya que si me los limpia y me coloca el texto Seleccionar ... pero los datos aun estan ahi y rompe el frujo en cascada.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si aplicas la seleccion que usa el `val()` deberia funcionar

Realice este ejemplo que lo comprueba

```js
$(function(){

   $("#button1").click(function(){
   
      $("[id*='ddlAños']").val(0);
      
   });
  
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="ddlAños" >
   <option value="0">option0</option>
   <option value="1">option1</option>
   <option value="2">option2</option>
   <option value="3">option3</option>
</select>

<br/><br/>

<button id="button1" >Reiniciar Seleccion</button>
```

Solo ejecutalo y veras como puede seleccionar cualquier item del combo y al presionar el boton volvera al primer item.

Si necesitas limpiar los items de `select` usarias

```
$("[id*='ddlAños']").empty();
```

el `empty()` quitar los opcions

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tittini es correcto el código me limpia los dropdown pero estos son en cascadas y se queda con los elementos. Solo quiero que mi primer dropdown tenga elementos aparte del elemento Seleccionar.

Comment: edite la repsuesta agregando la forma en que elimonas los options